# Xcode 10 and Xcode 11 continuously crashing when trying open existing application

Tags: crash, xcode10

Currently I'm using Xcode 10, Last week I have updated my mac.
Trying to open existing applications but getting crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the project directory and open you project workspace as show package contents by right click on workspace and choose 3rd option i.e. show package content 
and then delete xuserdata folder and try to open project again.